# PayPal and payment implementation

Tags: authentication, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-rest-sdk

I am designing a website that accepts payment through simple PayPal or Stripe buttons, but also has a section that pays out users through PayPal. What is the best way to do this?

Current setup: The user builds up coins through an action (NDA won't allow me to discuss in detail) and when their coins reach a certain amount, they can cash out in real $. I have designed this flow: Pay Me Now Button -> Screen with PayPal email address input. Repeat email for typos, then Confirm Button -> Success screen

However, the client would prefer a direct link out to PayPal instead of manual input of email addresses. The reasoning is that they would prefer it being arranged through PP's service to reduce manual errors and typing out. As far as I am aware the only way to get paid is through writing down an email address/phone number. I have researched PayPal.me buttons but it still isn't making sense. Maybe there's another service altogether that I can suggest to the client for paying out users in a no-friction way?

I'm looking at how user testing sites pay people, but not getting very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the money is in your client's PayPal account and they wish to send it to a user's email address (that may or may not have a PayPal account already), this can be automated with [PayPal Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts).

If the user does not have a PayPal account already they will receive an email notification and have 30 days to create an account or add the email to an existing account. If they don't, the payment will be refunded automatically.